# cross browser remove element from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an array of numbers which are values of the data-cardNumber attribute of different element in my site.

I'm trying to remove the value of the data-cardNumber attribute of the element that has that attribute that also has the class .lastBeenDragged.

I am trying this, but I think I may have oversimplified my code too much.

When I console.log the array before and after executing this code there is no change in the array.

How can I properly and cross browserly remove an element, the value of the data-cardNumber of the element with the class .lastBeen Dragged, from the array swipedAwayCards ?

Here is the code:

```
if(swipedAwayCards.indexOf($('.lastCardDragged').attr('data-cardNumber')) > -1) swipedAwayCards.splice(swipedAwayCards.indexOf($('.lastCardDragged').attr('data-cardNumber')), 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var v = $('.lastCardDragged').attr('data-cardNumber');
for (var i = 0, l = swipedAwayCards.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (swipedAwayCards[i] == v) {
        swipedAwayCards.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes, that make sense. Unfortunately, when I console.log the array before and after that code it still has the value. May I show you a live version of a site with the code?

Comment: @gomangomango It's not necessary. Log the value of the data attribute and let me know.

Comment: It was undefined, but now I fixed it! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Since [Array.indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) is not supported crossbrowser, you can user [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/)

```
var index = $.inArray($('.lastCardDragged').attr('data-cardNumber'), swipedAwayCards);
if (index > -1) {
    swipedAwayCards.splice(index, 1);
}
```